# I want to pass JavaScript Objects as Arguments

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(o){
    o=o || {};
}

foo(one:1); // ???
    alert(foo(one); // ???


foo(one:1,two:2,three:3) // ???
    alert(foo(one,two,three)); // ???
```

What exactly does this piece of JavaScript do?

```
o = o || {};
```

I've seen in many codes.

Comment: The original question asks about "o = 0 || {}", which is not actually what's in the code snippet, and which really makes no sense anyway.  It should be "o = o || {}".

Comment: @Pointy: I think it is a typo.

Comment: Yes I agree - I thought about editing it but decided instead to leave an explicit note.

Answer (score 4):

The expression

```
o = o || {};
```

means

> Interpret the value of the variable "o" as a boolean. If that value is "true", then set "o" to its current value. If "false", set "o" to refer to a new Object instance.

The point is to make sure that "o" is not null, and to initialize it to a new Object instance if it is.

As far as calling the function, you need to use the "object literal" notation:

```
foo({ key1: value, key2: value, ... });
```

*edit* — as noted in a comment, the **interpretation** of the value of "o" as boolean is a rather interesting subject of its own. In this particular case, the *intent* is to check to see whether "o" is null. There are values for "o" that evaluate to `false` but which *might* need to be treated differently here, but there's obviously not enough context in the question to know.

Comment: Not quite true or false.  Javascript variables can be truthy or falsy, and their truthy or falsy-ness determines how that result is evaluated.  Values of `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `'' (empty string)` and `NaN` are falsy, which means the expression `o = o || {};` is evaluated as such where if `o` is falsy, then `o = {};`

Comment: Yes, I know all that.  Note that I said, "interpret the value of the variable "o" as boolean."  That word "interpret" was meant to encapsulate exactly what you wrote :-)

Answer (score 2):

you would create your object

```
var arg = {key: val};
```

and then

```
var result = foo(arg);
```

you pass the object that is the argument into the function.  If your function can take more than one arg, when you define the function you would

```
   var theFunction = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        // arg1, arg2, and arg3 are all references in this function
   }
```

that way arg1, arg2, and arg3 are defined to be arguments.  Javascript has some flexibility in that you could pass as many arguments as you want in; it is good design to define the function with explicit arguments so the API is clear.  However, there are cases where you just don't know, so in Javascript you can get all the arguments that were passed in with the 'arguments' variable.  Javascript makes this variable available in all functions.  But you should use it rarely. Here is a link with examples

http://www.seifi.org/javascript/javascript-arguments.html

the

```
 o = o || {};
```

sets the variable 'o' to be o, or if o is not defined, an empty object literal.  It basically initializes the variable if it is 'falsy'.  It is a technique to prevent null object issues.